# Remember visited links in manual

Tags: hyperlinks, info

I am going through emacs inbuilt `Elisp` tutorial. By default emacs fontifies( changes color ) visited  links color like this

[image]

This fontification lasts only for current session. If i restart emacs, all fontification will be lost.

How  can i make  emacs to remember visited  links even after  restarting emacs so that it will be much easier for me to resume where  i have stopped?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The history of visited nodes is stored in the variable `Info-history-list`. You will need to persist this variable across sessions. One way to do so it to use `desktop-mode`. Desktop mode automatically persists the variables that are declared in `desktop-globals-to-save`. So if you use `desktop-mode` something like the following should doe the trick

```el
(add-to-list 'desktop-globals-to-save 'Info-history-list)
```

If you do not use desktop mode, you might have to write your own mechanism to persist the variable. Simplest would be write a function which runs on emacs exit (you can use the hook `kill-emacs-hook` to run the function at exit) that serializes the variable to a file using something like `prin1-to-string`.

You will then require another function which runs on emacs startup (you can use `after-init-hook` to run functions at startup) which reads the files and uses the function `read` to deserialize the the stored variable back. Of course this a lot of work to save a variable so I guess you can just use `desktop-mode`

Answer (score 5):

@Iqbal gives a great answer to your question.

You might also consider using **bookmarks** to record Info locations of interest, including a bookmark for where you left off (which you update at the next left-off place, by just setting it again).

This is simple to do, and is exactly what you would do with a book or multiple books that you are reading.